# How to detect touch on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, touch, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to disable UICollectionViewController's autorotation whenever there's a finger on the screen, as the iPhone photo app does.

How to do that?

- If use tap gesture, how to distinguish different touch states? (The state should be `touching`, even after finger moving.)
- If use `touchBegan:withEvent:`, where to put that code? (The hit view can be any subview of UICollectionView.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would set a flag in `touchesBegan` and clear it in `touchesEnded`.  Then in your `shouldAutoRotate` method you can check the flag and return false if the flag is set.

Something like this:

```
// In your UICollectionView subclass:

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Do stuff
    ...
    canRotate = NO;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Do stuff
    ...
    canRotate = YES;
}

// In your UICollectionViewController:

-(bool)shouldAutorotate
{
    return(canRotate);
}
```

Comment: Well, it works. I should overwrite touchesBegan: in UICollectionView. Why can't I just overwrite touchesBegan: in UICollectionViewController, which is a UIResponder too?

Comment: touchesBegan: is a UIViewController method too.