# UICollectionView Animate when touched

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to animate a UICollesctionView's Cell when it is touched? I've read there are several methods between didSelectItemAt with UIView.Animate or willDisplayCell with CAAnimations. Could someone please point me in the right direction in Swift? The goal is to tap the cell and have it scale/ change x position

Comment: Factory methods here are in Obj-C, but the Xcode should steer you in the right direction for Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22487238/4475605

Answer (score 0):

I will choose "didSelectItemAt", with "UIView.animate"

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    animatedImage = UIImageView(frame: cell.frame)
    animatedImage.image = ...

    view.addSubview(animatedImage)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.animatedImage.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: {(finished) in
            ...
        })
}
```